# rails 4 has_secure_password render password confirmation optional

Tags: ruby-on-rails

with rails 4 i use **has_secure_password** in my user model , trick says that if i don't set the :password_confirmation it will never be triggered but why when i run the test i get error : **Password confirmation can't be blank** as the following :

```
Failures:

1) User 
 Failure/Error: it { should be_valid }
   expected #<User id: nil, name: "joe", email: "joe@mail.com", created_at: nil, 
   updated_at: nil, password_digest: "$2a$04$mcRr/msgYQR3kBVc3kv/m.UotBJuJuSXZKMw
   /eHTvU87..."> to be valid, but got errors: Password confirmation can't be blank
```

my test file look like :

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

   before { @user = User.new(name: 'joe', email: 'joe@mail.com', password: 'foo') }

   subject { @user }
   #....
   #....
   describe "when password is not present" do
     before { @user.password = "" }
     it { should_not be_valid }
   end
end
```

why i get this error, there is a solution for that ? thank's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your test's `before` line to this:

```
before { @user = User.new(
  name: 'joe',
  email: 'joe@mail.com',
  password: 'foo',
  password_confirmation: 'foo')  #<== this line!
}
```

That should fix it.

**What this is about:**

You know how when you create a new account on pretty much any website, they ask you to make up a password and enter it twice?  That's what this is.  When you create a new user, `has_secure_password` wants the password twice to make sure you didn't make a typo.

If `password` != `password_confirmation`, it will throw an exception and the user won't be created.

Again, this is only used on user **creation**.  You don't need to enter two passwords in the login form or anything else.  **You don't have to add this field to your model or DB.**

If you have a user creation form, and you don't want to have a `password_confirmation` field, then you don't have to.  You can set `password_confirmation = password` in your controller, before you call save or whatever.

But for User **creation**, the `password_confirmation` **must** be present.

Comment: but i wouldn't add password_confirmation to my app, i need just a password once

Comment: It's only used during user creation.  You don't have to (and are not supposed to) add it to your model.  This is a feature of `has_secure_password`.

Comment: i don't understand please can you explain more ! (in my form i would juste a field for password and not another for password confirmation)

Comment: I added more to my answer.

Comment: i think this is the best solution for the time being, for completeness there is a fix of this issue in rails edge and the rule says that If you don't need the confirmation validation, just don't set any value to the password_confirmation attribute and the validation will not be triggered. this fix will be in rails 4.1. this is the link https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/11107#issuecomment-21850919. thank you

Comment: Good find.  I didn't know it was supposed to be any other way.

Answer (score 21):

**Long story short**

```
has_secure_password validations: false # This is the key to the solution
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 } # Or an length you want
```

**The Long story**

1. The [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html) and [the source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b965ce361b89ad33a4a4b422f8e564233926c723/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb#L42) say:

   > If you don’t need the confirmation validation, just don’t set any value to the password_confirmation attribute and the the validation will not be triggered.
2. But they also say:

   > Validations for presence of password on create, confirmation of password
   >     (using a +password_confirmation+ attribute) are automatically added. If
   >     you wish to turn off validations, pass validations: false as an
   >     argument. You can add more validations by hand if need be.
3. Item #1 is not a complete description. We need to turn off all validation
   and add our own validation rules to make this work like as described in point #2.

I spent sometime on this and got a lesson: find the source code when you are confused. This seems to be a painful way or hard way, but sometime it's the right way.

Comment: presence: true won't work as validations: false removes presence condition. However, since minimum length is 6, it won't matter

Comment: Rails 4 completely ignores the confirmation if you don't send it as a parameter so if you forget to whitelist the `password_confirmation` attribute, it will be ignored and your validations won't say a thing. Careful of this!

Comment: @shailesh `validations: false` only removes the default validations added by `has_secure_password`.  Adding custom validations like `presence: true` on the password field will still work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

I did this as a temporary measure until I get this app from Rails 4.0.13 to 4.1 and beyond:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  # Tempfix until Rails 4.1 https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/11107#issuecomment-21850919
  raise "Get rid of this on Rails 4.1+" if Rails::VERSION::STRING != "4.0.13"
  before_validation { self.password_confirmation ||= password }
end
```

Comment: What exactly does this do, does it remove the validation or make password confirmation equal to password?

Comment: @SurgePedroza The latter. If the confirmation is nil, it gets assigned the password value before validations run.