# Disable the has_secure_password password_confirmation check in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, passwords

I'm creating a basic Ruby on Rails 4 project that allows user to create accounts, login, etc... I'm using the built in `has_secure_password` to manage the password. I don't want users to have to enter their password twice (i.e. require a `password_confirmation` input form field and corresponding model attribute). So, I'm looking for a way to turn the `password_confirmation` check/requirement off.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18863258/102401) that provides a potential solution, but the original question is different enough that I want to verify it separately. It recommends updating the user model to add the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # ...

  has_secure_password validations: false
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }

end
```

This seems to work and allows my RSpec tests to pass. My two part question is:

1. Are there any negative consequences or security problems with this approach?
2. Are there alternate ways to turn off `password_confirmation` that are safer or more inline with "The Ruby Way"?

Answer (score 13):

[ActiveModel::SecurePassword](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb) has an options parameter to which you can specify not to perform validations.

```
has_secure_password validations: false
```

Then just make sure you perform a validation on your password field manually.

```
validates_presence_of :password, on: :create
```

Optionally the only other thing missing is to raise an error if the password_digest is somehow blank. I don't know how that could happen.

```
before_create { raise "Password digest missing on new record" if password_digest.blank? }
```

This seems to me resolves the issue as cleanly as possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you'll take a look at [ActiveModel::SecurePassword](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb), you'll see the validations created by has_secure_password.

```
if options.fetch(:validations, true)
      validates_confirmation_of :password, if: :should_confirm_password?
      validates_presence_of     :password, on: :create
      validates_presence_of     :password_confirmation, if: :should_confirm_password?

      before_create { raise "Password digest missing on new record" if password_digest.blank? }
end
```

by disabling validations, you're also preventing the check for the field `:password_digest`, which isn't a huge deal but still not ideal.

I think the better option is to override the default method, `should_confirm_password?`

```
# If password_confirmation is passed, business as usual.
# If not, don't run the validations
def should_confirm_password?
    password_confirmation.present? || false
end
```

Comment: I don't think this is accurate in Rails 6 anymore. The approved answer is the better one.

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 6, AFAICT (didn't check other versions), you simply don't pass a `password_confirmation` attribute to your model. It is not required by default.

See https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/confirmation.rb#L75