# Rails 4, not saving @user.save when registering new user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

When I try to register an user, it does not give me any error but just cannot save the user.
I don't have `attr_accessible`. I'm not sure what I am missing. Please help me.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  validates :email, presence: true,
                    uniqueness: true,
                    format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 6}
  validates :nickname, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)             # Not saving @user ...
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Successfully registered"
      redirect_to videos_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Cannot create an user, check the input and try again"
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :nickname)
  end
end
```

**Log:**

```
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",    "authenticity_token"=>"x5OqMgarqMFj17dVSuA8tVueg1dncS3YtkCfMzMpOUE=", "user"=>{"email"=>"example@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "nickname"=>"example"}, "commit"=>"Register"}
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'example@example.com' LIMIT 1
User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."nickname" = 'example' LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  rollback transaction
```

Comment: Have you verified in the database that no user record is created?

Comment: Yes, there is no user record in my database.

Comment: Is `@user.save` returning `true` or `false`?

Comment: @ChrisPeters it returns `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

High chances that error is in password confirmation. You use `has_secure_password` from Rails, which automagically handles password confirmation for you. And here is the problem - you don't have it before user creation. Thus just add. For details check out similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954996/rails-4-has-secure-password-render-password-confirmation-optional) on `has_secure_password`

And check, that you have `password_digest:string` in users table :)

Comment: I finally solved this issue by adding `has_secure_password validations: false` in `models/user.rb` Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Regarding our short discussion in the comments, it appears that one or two things are happening to cause `@user.save` to return `false`:

- One of the validation rules are failing
- A callback within your model is returning `false`, thus halting processing and rolling back the transaction

There are a few quick ways to debug the validations. I figured I could describe them so you could learn a few options.

A. Change the call within the `if` statement to instead use the bang method of `save`:

```
if @user.save!
```

This will cause the app to raise an exception if validation fails, displaying the validation errors within the browser on your screen. In this particular scenario, you'd want to remember to remove the `!` after you're done debugging because you probably don't want the final version of your app doing that.

Or...

B. Within the `else` statement, add this line:

```
raise @user.errors.to_yaml
```

This will display the validation errors within the browser on the screen. Of course, remember to remove this line after you're done debugging.

Or...

C. Within the `else` statement, add this line and then run the form post:

```
puts @user.errors.to_yaml
```

This will display the validation errors within your console. You'll want to remember to remove this line after you're done debugging, but it's "less worse" if you happen to forget because at least the extra info is only output to `STDOUT`.

You may want to try each of these just to get a little practice and to see what your options are in simple debugging scenarios like this.

Comment: Thank you so much for these debugging procedures, these are really helpful techniques that I did not know! I will use these!

Comment: You're welcome. I think there are better debugging tools that I should look into, but this usually works pretty well for me. Good luck with your app!